# How to remove end of line para while inserting paragraph VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am inserting paragraph range from one doc to another.
for example

```
arrList1 = oRow.Range.Cells(2).Range.Paragraphs(2).Range.Text
some code
oNewRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = arrList(lngIndex - 1) & vbCr & arrList1
```

code is in trial and error.

The problem with above code is it insert in `oNewRow.Cells(2).Range.Text` at the end one paragraph. How to prevent that para from happening.

My `oRow.Range.Cells(2).Range.Paragraphs(2).Range.Text` always ends without paragraph means there are only 2 paragraphs in Cell 2. I don't know from where extra paragraph is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `vbCr` is creating a new paragraph. Try `vbLF` or `vbCrLf` to see if one of those gives you the desired format.

**Update:** You have a trailing carriage return on `arrList1`, so you want to trim the carriage return character `char(13)`. Try adding this after you set the `arrList1` variable:

```
arrList1 = oRow.Range.Cells(2).Range.Paragraphs(2).Range.Text
If Right(arrList1, 1) = Chr(13) Then
    arrList1 = Left(arrList1, Len(arrList1) - 1)
End If
```

Comment: Tried both. Didn't remove para. The para is actually at the end and I am using vbcr in between. Para is comming because of arrList1.

Comment: @Rahul I've updated my answer to trim the trailing paragraph from `arrList1`. I'm not sure where the extra paragraph is coming from without looking at your project, but hopefully trimming it off will get your project moving forward.